# Having graphical issues in Eclipse and other apps

Tags: arch-linux, gui

My current installation of Manjaro linux is having some graphical issues in Eclipse and other apps.

Text is misaligned, padding is sometimes missing and other general graphical glitches occur.

I am guessing that Eclipse and the other apps are using a shared library 
 for rendering under the hood which has broken somehow.

**This is how it looks right now:**

[image: Screenshot of Eclipse with graphical issues]

Does anyone know what is at fault here and how I would go about fixing it?

**EDIT**: I was able to find the same graphical glitches in the Nvidia X Server Settings application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I asked the same question in the Manjaro Forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=33540) and got the following solution:

---

Those issues are related to the latest gtk3.20 changes, a lot of themes are broken now.

Also, the manjaro xfce main theme switches from menda to maia, so your problems are solved when you switch to our new theme (available in dark and normal and just beautiful :))

```
sudo pacman -S vertex-maia-themes vertex-maia-icon-theme
```

then go to

```
xfce4-appearance-settings
```

-> switch theme and icon theme to vertex-maia

then go to

```
xfmw4-settings
```

-> switch theme to vertex maia (dark)

---

Thanks a lot to **svnset**!